# How to evaluate: $I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{k-\cos\theta}}$

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $k>1$. How to evaluate:
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{k-\cos\theta}}$$
Since $\cos\theta$ is even around $\theta=\pi$, we have:
$$I=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{k-\cos\theta}}$$
I use $x=\cos\theta$, then: $dx=-\sqrt{1-x^2}d\theta$:
$$I=2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{k-x}}$$
and then stuck...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

Comment: When $k=1$, it's a quick solution using the half angle formula. For $k \neq 1$, it's not an elementary integral I think.

Comment: Byrd and Friedman 291.00 immediately gives the answer as
$$\frac4{\sqrt{1+k}}K\left(m=\frac2{1+k}\right)$$ where $K$ is the complete first-kind elliptic integral and $m$ indicates the parameter (used by Mathematica/mpmath).